# Plotly JS range slider really slow with markers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to plot 15000 points using a range slider on the x axis with lines and markers. This is the [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/kiranbaktha/pen/ERpejP)

```
mode: 'lines+markers'
```

If the mode is only lines it is fast but with markers it seems to be really slow. Is there a way to make this faster? Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of nodes - and sadly you're experiencing a typical limitation of having that many nodes in the DOM (compounded by the extra 15 000+ nodes in the range slider). The main line is just one node (with a very detailed `d` attribute) which can be updated easily as compared with 15 000 points. I don't think plotly does canvas (canvas has no child nodes, unlike svg), but if you were drawing that many nodes with vanilla d3 you'd probably be using canvas. So, I'm not sure if there is a solution with plotly and keeping the markers that will reduce the delay caused by so many nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest and alternate method for plotting a million datapoints, plotly offers `webGL` for plotting this. Get to know more about this by clicking [here](https://plot.ly/python/webgl-vs-svg/).

So I have implemented a solution for your case. But there is a minor predicament, when I plot, the actual data provided, all I get is a single line of markers, I checked and its due to plotly being unable to handle this large number of digits.

To handle this. We need to reduce the number length after the decimal from 16 to 9, then the data is getting plotted properly.

So the number `1439856801592000.0` should be reduced to `801592000.0`, then I am getting the desired solution.

Please refer the below codepen, which implements `scattergl`, try it out and let me know if this solves your problem!

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Comment: @KiranBaktha Range slider is not supported I guess, I am unable to make it work!

Comment: Yeah...Thanks for trying

Comment: Look into https://plotly.com/python/webgl-vs-svg/
There's is a js version